# Python: add column to loaded csv file without changing the csv file

Tags: python, numpy, csv, vector

I have a csv file which I was wondering if I could add a column in the end to? Without changing the actual Excel file.

My idea is that I have a csv file where I have the different mean values in rows calculated in a vector (numpy) and this I wanted to add as a column so I get the mean of each row added as a column in the end.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, load the csv file into a pandas dataframe.
then add column to the dataframe.

Below is a sample pseudocode :

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['new_column'] = 'some_value'
or
df['new_column'] = df['existing_column'].apply(some_function)
```

Comment: Thank you! The new value I add, can that be my vector? And can I also give it a name?

So I have a vector and then actually first add a name to the vector and then add it as a column?

Comment: I made it work!!!!!! That is amazing! Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: Do you by any chance know, that now that I have my new file with added column, can I then order it by alphabetical order by a specific column? Somehow say "order by alphabetical order by column 2" ??